# Focus Shape Inside Expo Camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera, expo

I am trying to have a focus area shape in my live camera like the picture below (circle is where one would take the image while everything out of the circle is darkened). I am currently using the expo camera exactly how it is shown in the code below. Does anyone know how I could add in a circle or square on top of this so that the user would know exactly where to take a picture of an object. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            type={this.state.type}
            flashMode={this.state.flashMode}
            ref={(camera) => (this.camera = camera)}
            zoom={this.state.cameraZoomValue}
            autoFocus={Camera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
            whiteBalance={Camera.Constants.WhiteBalance.auto}
            faceDetectorSettings={{
              mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.accurate,
              detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.all,
              runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
              minDetectionInterval: 500,
              tracking: true,
            }}
            onFacesDetected={this.onFacesDetected}
            onFacesDetectionError={this.onFacesDetectionError}
          >
</Camera>
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to add some view with border(top, left, right, bottom) and setting position absolutely to achieve it. Here is my code(not sort out very clean), but I think it could help.

```js
import { StyleSheet, View ,Dimensions} from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
    const maskRowHeight = Math.round((height - 200) / 20);
    const maskColWidth = (width - 200) / 2;
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
       <View style={styles.maskOutter}>
              <View
                style={[
                  { flex: maskRowHeight },
                  styles.maskRow,
                  styles.maskFrame
                ]}
              />

              <View style={[{ flex: 40 }, styles.maskCenter]}>
                <View style={[{ width: maskColWidth }, styles.maskFrame]} />
                <View style={styles.maskInner}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      width: "100%",
                      height: 10,
                      borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                      borderTopWidth: 1,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      width: "100%",
                      height: 10,
                      borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                      borderBottomWidth: 1,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      width: 20,
                      height: "100%",
                      borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                      borderLeftWidth: 1,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      width: 20,
                      height: "100%",
                      borderColor: "#FFFFFF",
                      borderRightWidth: 1,
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                      borderColor: "#00BED6",
                      borderTopWidth: 4,
                      borderLeftWidth: 4
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                      borderColor: "#00BED6",
                      borderTopWidth: 4,
                      borderRightWidth: 4
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                      borderColor: "#00BED6",
                      borderBottomWidth: 4,
                      borderLeftWidth: 4
                    }}
                  />
                  <View
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                      borderColor: "#00BED6",
                      borderBottomWidth: 4,
                      borderRightWidth: 4
                    }}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={[{ width: maskColWidth }, styles.maskFrame]} />
              </View>
              <View
                style={[
                  { flex: maskRowHeight },
                  styles.maskRow,
                  styles.maskFrame
                ]}
              >                
              </View>
            </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {    
    flex:1
  },
  cameraView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  maskOutter: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-around"
  },
  maskInner: {
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: "transparent"    
  },
  maskFrame: {    
    backgroundColor: "#1C355E",
    opacity: 0.7
  },
  maskRow: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  maskCenter: { flexDirection: "row" },
  rectangleText: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white"
  }
});

export default App;
```

looks like this...[image]

And you could change color what you want.

[Code on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-greider-y9mfu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I guess just put start from`maskOutter` in your camera view tag would be work.